# How can I get the burnt fees of each Ethereum's block from geth?

Tags: etherscan

I try to use the latest version of a Python wheel called web3 to get the detailed information of each Ethereum's block from geth. But I can't get the burnt fees of each Ethereum's block? How can I get this information from geth?